Invariant Violation: TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(...): 'RNGestureHandlerModule'

Invariant Violation: TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(...):
'RNGestureHandlerModule' could not be found. Verify that a module by
this name is registered in the native binary.Bridgeless mode: true.
TurboModule interop: true. Modules loaded:
{"NativeModules":[],"TurboModules":["PlatformConstants","LogBox","SourceCode","AppState","BlobModule","WebSocketModule","DevSettings","DevToolsSettingsManager","Networking","Appearance","DevLoadingView","DeviceInfo","ImageLoader","SoundManager","IntentAndroid","DeviceEventManager","NativeAnimatedModule","I18nManager"],"NotFound":["NativePerformanceCxx","NativePerformanceObserverCxx","RedBox","BugReporting","HeadlessJsTaskSupport","LinkingManager","NativeReactNativeFeatureFlagsCxx","RNCSafeAreaContext","ReanimatedModule","RNGestureHandlerModule"]}

i want to know the root cause of this issue, While debugging i found all these modules mentioned are null.
What is the thing that is causing these types of isses, Checked so many issues but no one has given the root cause of these issues.
"NotFound":["NativePerformanceCxx","NativePerformanceObserverCxx","RedBox","BugReporting","HeadlessJsTaskSupport","LinkingManager","NativeReactNativeFeatureFlagsCxx","RNCSafeAreaContext","ReanimatedModule","RNGestureHandlerModule"]}
-> https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-gesture-handler/issues/2847
-> https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-gesture-handler/issues/2749

react-native: 0.74.3 react-native-gesture-handler: "2.17.1",


If you're using iOS and installing react-native-gesture-handler for the first time, make sure you kill the app in Xcode and rebuild it from there. Just reloading the app by running yarn react-native start --reset-cache is not sufficient to get a fully rebuilt app with the necessary RNGestureHandlerModule module installed.

Try downgrading react-native-gesture-handler to version 2.15.0.
This issue seems to only affect a few people so I imagine that it's a package dependency issue/local setup issue.
There's an active issue in https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-gesture-handler/issues/2847 here though so hopefully it will get fixed soon.

Unfortunately didn't help me.

@DavidKo I think the package has been updated to fix this issue now, maybe try installing the latest version.
